# How to Transform Voronoi Mosaic into a Graph in R?

Tags: r, graph, voronoi

I would like to convert a Voronoi mosaic into an undirected graph using R. How?

```
library(mvtnorm)
library(tripack)
set <- rmvnorm(100,c(0,0),diag(2))
voronoi <- (voronoi.mosaic(set[,1],set[,2]))
plot(voronoi)
```

[image]

```
1,2
2,3
3,4
1,4
...
```

I would prefer to use R but in case you have a nifty solution in another language I'd like to hear about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `igraph` package is a fairly complete graph analysis package. It has a variety of functions for creating graphs out of different data structures. In your case I think you'll want the function `graph.edgelist`.

Comment: graph.edgelist cannot convert a voronoi-object into a graph

Comment: after taking a second look at the composition of the returned voronoi object I can confirm that your answer is reasonably close to how this can be done

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question with an answer that contains the code to do this. It might be useful to others.

Comment: sure - but the question is obviously low quality given the -1 votes - so why would somebody care for an answer?